# Custom Segue Class UIView Animation Issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am having trouble creating a custom segue using swift 3 and iOS 8. I am trying to transition between view controllers by fading from one VC to a black screen and then fading from black to my second VC. I tried to implement the segue by creating a custom segue using the code below, but it is not working as I would like it to. My goal is to perform an animation when the black square goes from 0.5 alpha to 1.0 alpha, then present my second view controller, then set the black square from 1.0 alpha back to 0.5 alpha and delete it. Right now, it does the first part correctly but after the animation finishes you can see the first VC for a brief instant before the second VC pops up. How should I change my code to make the transition smoother and get the desired result?

```
override func perform() {
    let sourceVC = self.source
    let destinationVC = self.destination

    let square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    square.alpha = 0.5
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    sourceVC.view.addSubview(square)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        square.alpha = 1.0
    })

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.2, animations: { 
        square.alpha = 0.5
    }) { (finished) in
        sourceVC.present(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below and try:

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        square.alpha = 1.0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.2, animations: { 
                    square.alpha = 0.5
                }) { (finished) in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      sourceVC.present(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    })
    }
```

Comment: well it fixed the old issue, but now the second part of the animation doesn't seem to run. The black square goes to 1.0 alpha and then seems to disappear and the destinationVC appears instead.

Comment: Write all UI updation task in this block DispatchQueue.main.async {    } like updating alpha etc.

Comment: When I add the square.alpha = 0.5 into the DispatchQueue.main.async block, it causes SourceVC to immediately change to DestinationVC without using the square animation at all. It is as if there is just a normal show segue.

Comment: So try to increase duration timing

Comment: I increased both animations to 2 second durations and it still doesn't show

Comment: let me know if still have issue

Comment: It is back to the original issue where the sourceVC shows while the square is going from 1.0 to 0.5 alpha and then the destinationVC pops up.